# How to publish a Mathematica notebook to a journal as supplementary material?

Tags: pdf-format, printing, html, publishing

I've done part of a proof via Mathematica. In the appendix of the paper I've linked to this published notebook, since I misunderstood "With any paid subscription plan, all files stored in the Wolfram Cloud never expire.". I just found out that when your subscription ends the published cloud files cannot be accessed anymore, which makes this feature useless for publishing papers. When I publish a mathematical paper I want it to be still accessible in hundreds of years.

So I've tried to save my notebook as pdf or LaTeX, which both gives terrible results. The pdf basically just shows a bunch of random characters instead of the actual content and the LaTeX code gives multiple errors when I try to compile it and it is not able to make proper line breaks, such that the formulas are cut off.
HTML works kind of okay-ish in the sense that one can guess the content most of the time since the majorities of symbols are shown kind of correctly (some curly brackets are not shown). Is there any possibility to put a version of a Mathematica notebook into a publication that is readable for everyone without the need of any license. At least something like a screenshot of my monitor (but the notebook does not fit on one notebook as it spans over multiple pages). Am I doing something wrong when I try to save my notebook as pdf (or print it)? I can barely believe that such an expensive software as Mathematics fails so hard in implementing such a basic feature. The save as PostScript is by the ways as buggy as the printing feature as well.

The pdf looks like this:
[image] and I don't really see how this is connected to my notebook.

E.g.,if I create the simplest Mathematica notebook I can think of:
[image]

The result looks like this:

[image]
which is completely useless. If it doesn't work for this simple example, I ask myself the question if there ever was a single case in the history of Mathematica, where the "save to pdf" feature actually gave a kind of useful result?

Comment: As far as I understand, [Wolfram Player](https://www.wolfram.com/player/) is free, and anyone can use it to open notebooks. As for the PDF: The output obviously shouldn't look like that if you use File > Save as > PDF. Search through this StackExchange for similar problems with PDF export, or post a separate question about this.

Comment: Is there some promise by Mathematica that they will always offer this for free and that they release it as open source software in case they go bankrup. Otherwise it doesn't really solve the problem. Something like a pdf would be more reliable as a backup and it would be more convenient for readers of the paper whop do not want to install additional software on their device. I think there are much more people that have a pdf reader installed than people that have Wolfram Player installed.

Comment: My suggestion is that you upload your notebook on a public hosting site.
If you can rework your mathematica notebook into a package, then you can very easily upload it and store it on GitHub. Alternatively consider some online cloud storage such as a public Dropbox, GDrive,etc...? I'm not sure. 

I often see PDF excerpts of mathematica. To my knowledge, people don't shy too much from simply rewriting a valuable piece of code.

Comment: Yes I can upload the .nb on GitHub and I can additionally recommend via a readme-file to install Wolfram Player in order to open it without any license. But his only partially solves my problem. @alex do you know how one can get pdf excerpts? Maybe the print feature is only such a bad joke on my specific Matehmatica version on Linux and on other veriosns/systems this feature is actually meant seriously?

Comment: @Jakob, I suggest you ask a separate question with your problem regarding PDF.

Comment: I've made both notebooks and PDFs available in past. Save As > PDF works or fails in a platform-and-version-dependent manner. Which is both exasperating and deplorable. Not something I can fix though. If you have specific examples that fail they can be sent to Tech Support and will most likely get looked at (I hope). Of course both OS and version should be noted. Also: I use a Ubuntu Linux, and from what I can tell the Linuxes are more prone than other platforms to these issues.

Comment: @Domen: Yes, I've asked a separate question for the pdf problem here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282773/82534

Comment: @Daniel Lichtbau: Yes, I'll contact the Tech Support

Comment: PDF export may have its glitches but not in my experience at the level you encountered. Assuming you are saving from a notebook, please i. evaluate the notebook, ii. save your notebook normally and then ii. pick from the menus File > SaveAs and choose PDF document. Do not touch the provided file name; just press the Save button. Does this not work?

Comment: @Alan Yes, this is approximately what I did. To be sure I did it again, exactly as you asked for, and I get the same heavily flawed result. See also the thread dedicated to this PDF-problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282773/82534