# Pdf export is heavily flawed for simplest possible notebook such as a=b+c

Tags: pdf-format, printing

File > save As ... > pdf (or print as pdf) gives me extremely bad results even for the most basic simplest possible Mathematica notebooks.

Here a simple example where I can reproduce the problem.

E.g.,if I create the simplest Mathematica notebook I can think of:
[image]

The result looks like this:

[image]
which is completely useless. If it doesn't work for this simple example, I ask myself the question if I have still a chance to get an acceptable results for any real world notebook more complicated than "a=b+c"?

For most of the software that I use it is rather the exception to observe bugs. For the Matehmatica print feature I was not able to ever observe a line of code which was not full of bugs. I have entered the most simple probably most tested line of code consisting of 6 characters and there are 4 severe mistakes in the resulting pdf.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this?

I am using Version Number 13.0.0.0 on Linux x86 (64-bit Fedora Linux 36)

Edit: Changing the font to Courier does not help:

[image]

looks like the following when saved as pdf:

[image]

Comment: Windows 10 13.2 Works for me.

Comment: In modern OSs, there is usually a way to _print_ something to a PDF file. Does it work if you do `File > Print... > Print to File`, and is this an acceptable workaround for you?

Comment: @Domen Yes, as I have mentioned already in my question I have exactly the same problem when I print the file to a pdf file (File > Print... > Print to File (PDF)

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that!

Comment: @Daniel Huber: Great, does it also work for real world notebooks with more complicated formulas beyond a=b+c on Windows? Then I'll try to find out if my license also covers a second installation on Windows 11. Anyone tried printing already on Windows 11?

Comment: It also works for more complicated notebooks.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this in my Debian 11 Bullseye VM. Does it behave better/differently if you evaluate the following before saving as PDF? `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {StyleHints, "CodeFont"}] = "Courier"`

Comment: @ihojnicki No, it does not get better, but it shows something different. I'll add pictures to my question

Comment: It works fine on Mac.

Comment: @Jakob, I would contact Tech Support, and give them the output from `SystemInformation[]`.  They will probably also want to know a few things about your setup.

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround allowed me avoid the bugs:

1. I saved my notebook to the cloud,
2. opened the notebook in the cloud via [wolframcloud.com](https://www.wolframcloud.com) (in the browser)
3. I used File > Print to PDF
4. and downloaded the resulting PDF, which looks fine (except hyperlinks: [Hyperlinks not preserved when saving in PDF format in Mathematica V13](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282891/82534)).

While I still have the same problems locally on Fedora. I don't face this problems in the cloud. So I can just simply use the cloud for printing as described above.