# Print to PDF issue on Wolfram Cloud (fine on Desktop)

Tags: wolfram-cloud, pdf-format

I have looked at the previous issues with text rendering when using print to PDF, and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282773/pdf-export-is-heavily-flawed-for-simplest-possible-notebook-such-as-a-bc) suggests using Wolfram Cloud due to missing fonts. However, I have consist problems when using Wolfram Cloud. It seems that as soon as I use a non-alphabet character (including basic =,+,;), the print to PDF rendering does not match with the input, even if I then delete the characters.

I want to use the cloud for teaching, so want instructions I can give students that aren't "install Mathematica/go to a computer lab"

Input:

[image: Mathematica notebook with title "Example of text", subsection "Exercise 1", and input "A=a+b;"]

PDF:

[image: Mathematica notebook with title "Example of text", subsection "Exercise 1", and input "C k c f phi" in various fonts]

I have tried Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, all up-to-date on Mac.

Comment: I can see the letters when I print to PDF from the cloud; [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qytlm.png).

Comment: @Syed I seem to not be able to replicate the issue in a new file, either. https://imgur.com/a/AHiAUuy. But it is definitely still there for my existing files.